# How to make MINA client message event fire?

Tags: java, kotlin, io, apache-mina

I'm making an app which requires client-server messaging. I decided to use MINA. The server works just fine (reads messages, fires events and writes responses, as in logs), but client seems to not fire any events. It logs sent messages, received bytes, but handler is never used. None of debug messages inside handler are printed. How can I make messageReceived event fire?

I'm using Linux server with 1.8.0_212 java, MINA version 2.1.2, Kotlin version 1.3.30

```
val connector = NioSocketConnector()

connector.filterChain.addLast("logger", LoggingFilter())
connector.filterChain.addLast("codec", ProtocolCodecFilter(TextLineCodecFactory(Charsets.UTF_8, System.lineSeparator(), System.lineSeparator())))

connector.handler = object: IoHandlerAdapter() {
    override fun sessionCreated(session: IoSession?)
        println("created session")
    }

    override fun event(session: IoSession?, event: FilterEvent) {
        println("event: ${event::class.java.simpleName}")
    }

    override fun messageReceived(session: IoSession?, message: Any) {
        println("received message: $message")
    }
}

val future = lobbyConnector.connect(InetSocketAddress("172.18.0.10",
Constants.SERVER_PORT))
future.awaitUninterruptibly()

val session = future.session
session.config.isUseReadOperation = true
```

I expect my handler to receive messages, but instead it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I'm so dumb, I just assigned different handler in other module, which didn't have debug